# Unnumbered sections and section marks

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

In my document I have numbered and unnumbered sections.
Unnumbered sections look like this:

```
\section*{Introduction}
```

I use fancyhdr and add section and subsection marks like this.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
\fancyhead[L]{\rule[-0.25in]{0pt}{0.25in}\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
  \hdrfont\textbf{\leftmark\\\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\hdrfont\thepage\ /~\pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\rule[-0.25in]{0pt}{0.25in}\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
  \hdrfont\textbf{\leftmark\\\rightmark}}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\hdrfont\thepage\ /~\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

As a result, the unnumbered sections are ignored in headers.

I tried to use this command in unnumbered sections

```
\sectionmark{Introduction}
```

Now, I have 0 index for these sections in headers.

How to fix this?
Any solutions to create unnumbered section which would be treated as numbered ones (without sectionmark, addcontentsline, ...)?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
\fancyhead[L]{\rule[-0.25in]{0pt}{0.25in}\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
  \textbf{\leftmark\\\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\rule[-0.25in]{0pt}{0.25in}\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
  \textbf{\leftmark\\\rightmark}}}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section1}
\lipsum[4-8]
\newpage
\section*{Section2}
\lipsum[4-8]
\newpage
\section{Section3}
\lipsum[4-8]
\newpage
\section*{Section4}
\lipsum[4-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: please provide a complete MWE starting with `\documentclass` and ending with  `\end{document}`, else people willing to help have to compose it themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue the appropriate `\markboth` command when doing `\section*`; the easiest method, without plunging in the depth of the definition of `\@startsection`, which won't probably work with `titlesec`, is to redefine `\section` with the help of `xparse`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xparse}
\let\CLASSsection\section

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% there's a *
    \CLASSsection*{#3}\markboth{#3}{}%
   }
   {% no *
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {% no opt arg
      \CLASSsection{#3}%
     }
     {% opt arg
      \CLASSsection[#2]{#3}%
     }%
   }%
}

\makeatletter
% fix \tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \section*{\contentsname}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother


% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}

\fancyhead[L]{%
  \bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\mbox{}\leftmark\\ \mbox{}\rightmark\end{tabular}%
}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\mbox{}\leftmark\\ \mbox{}\rightmark\end{tabular}%
}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Section1}
\lipsum[4-8]
\newpage
\section*{Section2}
\lipsum[4-8]
\newpage
\section{Section3}
\lipsum[4-8]
\newpage
\section*{Section4}
\lipsum[4-8]
\end{document}
```

I've also redefined how you set the headers and footers; a `tabular` is surely better than having loads of `Underfull \hbox` messages when there's no right mark to typeset. Also `\tableofcontents` needs to be redefined, because it normally issues `\@mkboth` (an alias for `\markboth`).

Don't forget to follow `fancyhdr`'s advice about increasing the `\headheight`; with this setting it requires just a bit less than 30pt.

Comment: Thanks, works fine. It seems like I still need to add addcontentsline in unnumbered sections, but I don't mind to do that. Thanks for unrelated fixes. Seems like you partially answered to my another question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168413/table-of-content-and-header).

Comment: @user14416 Just add `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#3}` after `\markboth{#3}{}` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

This uses `\pretocmd` to patch a suitable internal latex2e macro involved in typesetting starred sections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% checking compatibility
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers

\let\hdrfont\relax % don't know what this font is supposed to be
\AtEndDocument{\label{LastPage}} % very deficient work-around for LastPage which comes from some package.

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
\fancyhead[L]{\rule[-0.25in]{0pt}{0.25in}\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
  \hdrfont\textbf{\leftmark\\\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\hdrfont\thepage\ /~\pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\rule[-0.25in]{0pt}{0.25in}\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
  \hdrfont\textbf{\leftmark\\\rightmark}}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\hdrfont\thepage\ /~\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\providecommand\phantomsection{}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\@@@SECTION{section}
\pretocmd{\@startsection}{\def\@@@SECTIONING{#1}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@ssect}{%
   \expandafter\in@\expandafter{\@@@SECTIONING}{section,subsection}%
   \ifin@
     \phantomsection
     \addcontentsline{toc}{\@@@SECTIONING}{#5}%
     \ifx\@@@SECTIONING\@@@SECTION
          \markboth{#5}{}%
     \else\markright{#5}%
     \fi
   \fi}{}{}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section*{Introduction}

one\newpage
\section*{Unnumbered}

two\newpage
\section{Numbered}

three\newpage

\section{Again Numbered}

four
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have \usepackage[compact]{titlesec} probably and it spoils the solution. Any workaround?

Comment: @user14416 If you use `titlesec`, you should add it to your example.