# Table of content and header

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, header-footer

I have table of content in my document and header/footer with section, subsection marks.

When I include tocloft package I don't have header/footer anymore, that is not I want. On the other hand, I want to control spacing in the toc.

Another problem is that the toc leave a subsection mark in a header/footer.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{tocloft} % Uncomment this line

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
\fancyhead[L]{\rule[-0.25in]{0pt}{0.25in}\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
  \textbf{\leftmark\\\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\rule[-0.25in]{0pt}{0.25in}\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
  \textbf{\leftmark\\\rightmark}}}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section1}
\lipsum[4-8]
\newpage
\section*{Section2}
\lipsum[4-8]
\newpage
\section{Section3}
\lipsum[4-8]
\section*{Section4}
\lipsum[4-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`, so the package won't modify how the titles for the table of contents is typeset. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107616/package-tocloft-change-font-size

Answer (score 1):

See [Package tocloft change font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107616/package-tocloft-change-font-size) for a similar problem: the `tocloft` package, by default, changes the definitions for the starting page of the table of contents and the lists of figures/tables.

You can avoid this by calling

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```